# Java, Selenium, Debian for Raspberry Pi 4, geckodriver error prints garbage

Tags: java, selenium, debian, geckodriver, raspberry-pi4

Im making a Java program that uses Selenium to access webpages and retrieve data, it works on Windows, pure Debian and Ubuntu but when I run it on my RPI4 with Debian for Raspberry Pi 4, the geckodriver gives cryptic errors and the program crashes.

The errors are as follows:

```
/usr/local/bin/geckodriver: 2: /usr/local/bin/geckodriver: YM9sHIiHMIi԰: not found
/usr/local/bin/geckodriver: 1: /usr/local/bin/geckodriver: Syntax error: end of file unexpected (expecting ")")
/usr/local/bin/geckodriver: 1: /usr/local/bin/geckodriver: 6: not found
/usr/local/bin/geckodriver: 1: /usr/local/bin/geckodriver: : not found
/usr/local/bin/geckodriver: 1: /usr/local/bin/geckodriver: : not found
/usr/local/bin/geckodriver: 1: /usr/local/bin/geckodriver: 6: not found
/usr/local/bin/geckodriver: 1: /usr/local/bin/geckodriver: $/: not found
/usr/local/bin/geckodriver: 1: /usr/local/bin/geckodriver: GNUu¬wת,岹PXH: not found
/usr/local/bin/geckodriver: 1: /usr/local/bin/geckodriver: ELF: not found
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:29555
Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
System info: host: 'raspy', ip: '192.168.1.33', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'aarch64', os.version: '5.9.0-0.bpo.5-arm64', java.version: '11.0.9.1'
Driver info: driver.version: FirefoxDriver
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:92)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:213)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:131)
        at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:147)
        at net.ddns.creepercrack.Main.main(Main.java:40)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:29555
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connectSocket(RealConnection.java:247)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:165)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:257)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:135)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:114)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java:42)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
        at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.java:93)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:93)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:126)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
        at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:200)
        at okhttp3.RealCall.execute(RealCall.java:77)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.OkHttpClient.execute(OkHttpClient.java:103)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:105)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:74)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:136)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
        ... 5 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
        at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:399)
        at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:242)
        at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:224)
        at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:403)
        at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:609)
        at okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform.connectSocket(Platform.java:129)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connectSocket(RealConnection.java:245)
        ... 27 more
```

The program also creates this file: `''$'\001\022\002''@@'$'\230\204''y@8'$'\a''@'$'\035\032\001\005''@@t'$'\202''6t'$'\202''6'`, but I did not program that myself. This does not happen when the program works, only when it crashes.

It may be that it just does not work but I would like to know the answer.
The geckodriver is correcly in the PATH inside the program and is executable
Also, firefox-esr and default-jre.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. With regard to the "garbage" being printed when using
   'gekodriver', perhaps it is because its not meant for the platform
   (hardware + operating_system) you are using?
2. With regard to

> Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException:
> java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to
> localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:29555 Build info: version: 'unknown',
> revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown' System info: host: 'raspy', ip:
> '192.168.1.33', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'aarch64', os.version:
> '5.9.0-0.bpo.5-arm64', java.version: '11.0.9.1'

That would indicate that there is nothing listening on 29555 on tcp6 ip protocol.

Above are just guesses that you can try looking into until someone better informed comes along.

Comment: I was using an x86_64 version of geckodriver, obviously it won work on arm64.
The fix was to get an arm64 version of geckodriver, then it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I was using an x86_64 version of geckodriver, obviously it won work on arm64

The fix was to get and arm64 version of geckodriver, then it worked